# AngularJS App Randomly Freezes Page Using Angular Route With MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue where my angularjs app page will just randomly freeze. I have no while loops, but I do have watchers on some of the partial views that I am loading into the main page using angular-route templates. Would it be possible that these watchers are causing the app to randomly freeze? It is a very odd issue and I have put breakpoints throughout all of my code and I can't replicate the issue because it is extremely random with no way to trigger the issue. Occasionally Chrome will have the prompt to "Wait" or "Kill the Page" when a script is taking too long to execute but I have nothing running on my breakpoints.

I am currently using the latest version of AngularJS (1.7.9 minified through CDN), and all of the following libraries associated with AngularJS - angular-touch.min.js, angular-animate.min.js and angular-route.min.js.

I am also using the following JavaScript libraries: jQuery-UI 1.12.1, jQuery 1.12.4, lodash 1.8.3, ui-grid 4.7.1, angular-ui-bootstrap 1.3.2, and ngMask (also not used on every partial view).

The ui-grid is not always present so I doubt this has any effect on the issue, but I have never experienced the freezing occur on a view with a ui-grid.

I can provide code or additional information as needed. I haven't included any code because I can't replicate the issue nor have any idea where to start since it is such a random issue.

Comment: If it happens again, see if anything gets logged in the console and post it here.

Comment: That is the other frustrating part of this problem, no errors in the console on any browser.

Comment: Try to note if it only happens on one page/view or multiple views. If it only happens on one page, try and see if you see any problems in that views controller. If it happens in multiple views, it might be a shared piece of code causing the problem. Either way it should help narrow things down.

Comment: I will do that. I have also converted the application to run on its own application pool to hopefully isolate the issue further.